# Check for node modules being loaded using jasmine-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

So I'm trying to teach myself Jasmine (for node) by working through a tutorial for a Mongoose project, TDD style, writing tests for what each step is supposed to accomplish, then following the actual tutorial, etc.

Of course, my first test is failing.

app.js at this point is two lines:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
console.log(mongoose.version);
```

This runs fine.  My test however, still fails:

```
var app = require('../src/app.js');

describe('App startup', function() {
    it('loads mongoose', function() {
            expect(app.mongoose.version).toBeDefined();
    });
    it('loads jasmine-jquery', function() {
            expect($).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Results in

```
Failures:

1) App startup loads mongoose
Message:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
Stacktrace:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
at null.<anonymous> (/home/jbhelfrich/mongooseBlog/spec/init.spec.js:5:36)
```

(The jquery test is, of course, expected to fail still at this point.)  I've tried it with and without the 'app.' in the expect clause, but I get the same error--the test suite doesn't see the internals of app.js.  But I know it's loading the app.js file correctly, because it's running it--the console.log output appears ahead of the test results.

So I suspect I've misunderstood something fundamental about scope, or some other rookie mistake, but I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js is structured into modules. If you want a a module's properties to be accessible, that module's properties must be defined in the `module.exports` variable. This is what an export might look like (note that `exports` references `module.exports`):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
console.log(mongoose.version);
exports.mongoose = mongoose;
```

Then when you've used `require()` on a file with the code shown above, the variables will be set, where `app` is equivalent to `module.exports` in the module that is being loaded:

```
var app = require('../src/app.js');
console.log(app.mongoose.version);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!  Is there any reason (security, performance) to remove the exports.<module> lines from production code, or can they be left alone?

Comment: There's no reason to remove the exports because if you don't export variables then they are not accessible outside of the module.